# Need a small help in auto calculation form anyone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-calculation

anyone here good at js?

im looking for a form with following fields which would auto calculate and display the total on fly when i inpot the numbers in side the fields.

```
<input type="text" name="acutalprice" value="">Actual Price: 329
<input type="text" name="discount" value="">Discount: 65%
<input type="text" name="shipping" value="">Shipping: 50+
```

Total Amount: 165.15

on sumbit should get the total amount output

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should at least attempt writing some javascript/jquery code. You can experiment using [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/).

Comment: i do not know js else i sure would have given a try. would really appreciate if could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, add jQuery library to `<head></head>` part of your page. You should use [jQuery download page](https://jquery.com/download/) or [Google's Hosted Libraries page](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) to find jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you should put `<input>` elements into `<form></form>` element and add submit button for the form.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="actualprice" type="number" placeholder="Actual Price">
    <input id="discount" type="number" placeholder="Discount">
    <input id="shipping" type="number" placeholder="Shipping">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Finally, add script to the page for submitting the form.

```
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var actualprice = Number($("#actualprice").val().trim());
    var discount = Number($("#discount").val().trim());
    var shipping = Number($("#shipping").val().trim());

    var discountRate = (100 - discount) / 100;
    var result = (actualprice * discountRate) + shipping;

    $("#result").html("Result :" + result.toFixed(2));
});
</script>
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks you sooo much i really am thankful. need a little another bit of help on submit how do i get the results to print out on page so that i could store the form values as well as the total amount to database?

Comment: @Seeker i'm edit the answer, check this out now..

Comment: you are great thanking you soo very much,

Comment: you do NOT need to load the entire jQuery library for this - simple javascript will do the job without requiring jQuery. It is a simple javasript calculation on the submit of the form.

Comment: how to add the results inside a input text field rather than <h3 id="result"></h3>? also display the results on keyup event?